# Minimum number of cans needed to carry all used water

Tags: algorithms, arrays

so I've just attempted an online technical test. It was on hacker rank however I'm sure leetcode usually has the same (and more) so thought i'd ask.

I could not think of a nice solution and cannot find a leetcode exercise that matches what was being asked so I'm here for someone to point me in the right direction.

The problem:

Someone has to carry water in cans and can only carry one can at a time. I was given 2 arrays, one of which had the total amount of water each can can hold and the second has the amount of water that was currently used by each can. I had to find the minimum number of cans needed to carry the entirety of the used water.

An example input was:

Total =  [ 3 , 5 , 3 , 5 , 5]

Used = [ 3 , 2 , 1 , 3 , 1]

So can [0] has a total of 3 and is currently full. Can [1] has a total of 5 but only 2 is being used etc etc. I had to find the minimum amount of cans needed in order to be able to carry all of the water.
**The solution in this example was 2** since you could take the water from can [0] and put into can [1] to fill it up. You could then take water from cans [2] and [3] and put into can [4] therefore only needing cans [2] and [4] to carry all the water.

Does anyone recognise this question and could you be able to point me in the direction of the problem on leet code or hackerrank?  I cannot come up with a nice algorithm myself.

Comment: Please always, always, always include a reference to the original material. I repeated for three times so that, hopefully, no one will have to reminder you ever again.

Comment: Have you come up with any algorithm? If yes, please describe your idea.

Comment: @JohnL. I don't have it unfortunately, this is all from memory... If there's anything unclear maybe you could help by pointing it out to me instead so that I can edit my post?

Comment: @JohnL.   And the only horrible idea I can think of is to sum the used array. The example would be 10 units needed. We then need to find the minimum amount elements (cans) that sum up to equal 10 from the Total array, but not sure on best approach for this...

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, It is a first principle to include a reference. If you cannot find the reference, then you should say so (and probably say sorry, since it is generally considered your responsibility to find and present the reference); otherwise, some people may become irritated even if everything is perfectly clear.

Comment: Hint, greedy algorithm.

Comment: @JohnL. Cheers John, so I've answered the question and would appreciate any feedback or comments. This greedy algorithm concept is new to me

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after a nudge from @John in comments, I think this algorithm will work.

1. Count all elements in the Used array ( will get us 10 )
2. Sort the Total array
3. Can the iterate down the sorted Total array and take away each iteration from the total until its equal or less than 0.

This will only work on a sorted array since this is the only way of knowing that the and I quote 'global optimum can be arrived at by selecting a local optimum'. I.e we know that the next item is the biggest therefore it must be the biggest can. Need to read up on greedy algorithms and what actually makes this one greedy but I think this is the reason

Comment: This is the correct approach.

Comment: When writing an answer, keep in mind that you are writing them for others to learn from. This is not a place where you explain/exhibit your study plans, even if they are fantastic. You can always edit your questions and answers to improve them. (I did not downvote this question yet, though.)  People could read your questions and answers for many years.

Comment: Get where you're coming from, but I kinda feel someone reading this question then my algorithm to do it, is helping others to learn?

Comment: Sure. It is great that you posted an answer in addition to the question.

Comment: I will upvote the question if you can add the reference to the original problem. I will upvote the answer if several small typos have been fixed.